# Livewire: What is the proper way to save multiple images in the storage link and the name of the image in the database?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I tried to upload multiple images and want to save it to the storage and and name of the image into database but nothing happened next.

I dump the data from the view and I got this

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile {#1437 ▼
    +"disk": "local"
    #storage: Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter {#1384 ▶}
    #path: "livewire-tmp/pALAWPNYcMg4pm1w8EINqvURTuYH8x-metaRmFjZWJvb2stMDAxOS5qcGc=-.jpg"
    -test: false
    -originalName: "pALAWPNYcMg4pm1w8EINqvURTuYH8x-metaRmFjZWJvb2stMDAxOS5qcGc=-.jpg"
    -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "C:\Windows\Temp"
    filename: "pALAWPNYcMg4pm1w8EINqvURTuYH8x-metaRmFjZWJvb2stMDAxOS5qcGc=-.jpg"
    basename: "phpB58F.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\Windows\Temp\phpB58F.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: "C:\wamp64\www\cbcc-website\storage\app\livewire-tmp/pALAWPNYcMg4pm1w8EINqvURTuYH8x-metaRmFjZWJvb2stMDAxOS5qcGc=-.jpg"
    size: 554154
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
  1 => Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile {#1438 ▶}
  2 => Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile {#1436 ▶}
]
```

and this is my store function

```
public function store(){
        dd($this->gallery_image);

        $action = '';

        $data = $this->validate([
            'gallery_image.*' => 'image|max:1024',
        ]);

        if(!empty($this->gallery_image)){
            foreach ($this->gallery_image as $images) {
                $images->store('Gallery');
            }
        }
        
    
        if($this->galleryId){
            Gallery::find($this->galleryId)->update($data);
            $action = 'edit';
        }else{
            Gallery::create($data);
            $action = 'store';
        }
        $this->emit('showEmitedFlashMessage', $action);
        $this->resetInputFields();
        $this->emit('refreshParent');
        $this->emit('closeGalleryModal');

    }
```

Is there any better way to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you're using WithFileUploads in your component.

It doesn't look like you're saving the files to disk anywhere in your code, all you're doing is recording the file upload to the database.

This is how I'm doing it for a thing I just wrote. In this scenario the public variable uploaded files is wire:bound to your image field, and setup step is the entity that the files table is referencing. My code calls this to actually store the files to disk. It's not complete, because i don't have thumbnail resizing in yet, but it should still give you a good idea of how to do it.

```
    public function saveUploadedFiles() {
        if (!empty($this->uploaded_files)) {
            foreach ($this->uploaded_files as $file) {
                $this->active_file = new File;
                $this->active_file->filetype = $file->getMimeType();
                $this->active_file->filename = Str::uuid()->toString();
                $this->active_file->filesize = $file->getSize();
                $this->active_file->order = 0;
                $this->active_file->filepath = '/files/setupsteps/' . $this->active_file->filename;
                if (strpos($this->active_file->filetype, 'mage') !== false) {
                    $this->active_file->thumbnail = '/files/thumbnails/setupsteps/' . $this->active_file->filename;
                } else {
                    $this->active_file->thumbnail = asset('images/placeholder.jpg');
                }
                $this->active_file->created_by = auth()->id();
                $this->active_file->updated_by = auth()->id();
                $this->uploadFile($file);
                $this->active_step->files()->save($this->active_file);
            }
            $this->active_step->touch();
            $this->files = $this->active_step->files;
        }

    }

    public function uploadFile($file) {
        $file->storeAs('files/setupsteps/',$this->active_file->filename,'public');
        if (strpos($this->active_file->type,'image') !== false){
            $file->storeAs('files/thumbnails/setupsteps/',$this->active_file->filename,'public');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already have data when i `dd($this->gallery_image)` but when I `dd`  the validation nothing happened when uploading multiple image
```
$data =  $this->validate([
            'gallery_image.*' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max
        ]);

        dd($data);
```

Comment: ahh i see.  Is this being called in a foreach loop? I'm not using an actual form with mine, so I just have validation in $protected rules= $yourrulesarray at the top of my component.  That way it's being immediately validated when i click the button that calls my store routine, and not in the middle of adding files.  I'm not currently checking for size though.

Comment: yeah I'm using the foreach as what stated in the documentation

Comment: Maybe try the validate above the foreach loop?